# QtCreator: Loading External Library

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

So I've been developing a small ACARS (plane tracking system) for the VATSIM network and apart of this entails using the FSUIPC library to interact with Flight Sim X. I have the program working beautifully in VS2010 but when I attempt to use any functions from FSUIPC I get the error:

**"mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol FSUIPC_Open referenced in **function "public: void __cdecl MainWindow::connectFSUIPC(void)" (?connectFSUIPC@MainWindow@@QEAAXXZ)"****

From some research I've learnt that this is a library load error and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it working. Below is the code for all files I am using.

**AcarsTest.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-12-16T23:56:06
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AcarsTest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
         mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += "D:/Windows/QT/Tools/QtCreator/bin/AcarsTest/"
LIBS += -LD:/Windows/QT/Tools/QtCreator/bin/AcarsTest/ -lFSUIPC_User
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <FSUIPC_User.h>


namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void connectFSUIPC();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "FSUIPC_User.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::connectFSUIPC()
{
    DWORD dwResult;

    if(FSUIPC_Open(SIM_ANY, &dwResult))
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try change code like this

your code:

```
LIBS += -LD:/Windows/QT/Tools/QtCreator/bin/AcarsTest/ -lFSUIPC_User
```

replace by

```
win32:LIBS += "D:/Windows/QT/Tools/QtCreator/bin/AcarsTest/FSUIPC_User.lib"
```